# SMS script not sending in one server

Tags: php, server, sms

I have a weird issue. I have the following SMS script working fine in one web server (not local), yet when I move this to my client server this is not working/triggering.

```
    <?php 
$headers = "From: mytestsestserver<dev@domain.com>\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$rand_val = rand();
$msg = "SMS from test server (txt)" . $rand_val;
$success = @mail("XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net", $msg,  $headers);

if($success) {
    echo 'Success ' . $rand_val;
} else {
    echo 'failed!';
}
```

Where XXXXXXXXX is the phone number I'm using to send SMS to, and the email dev@domain.com is my personal email account.

I've tried to figure this out for days and have hit a brick wall. Maybe I'm missing something obvious here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the SMS mechanic works, the only other thing that would cause this (aside from the PHP simply not executing) is a problem with SMTP email, test by sending one to a different email address.

Comment: thanks for the reply. at first i was using a google apps for domain gmail.com account. to make sure that is not the issue, i changed it to a personal normal gmail.com account. tried it on my personal web server and it worked, moved it to client web server and it did not.

Comment: if you swap XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net for another email you have, do you receive the message?

Comment: XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net is not an email. it is the phone number the SMS is sent to.

Comment: Yes but this is an email-to-sms gateway isn't it? You *email* (@mail) <phone>@txt.att.net,  ATT receive the email then forward it as an  SMS for you.  Change `XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net` on the system that does work to one of your email addresses and you'll get an email with the message text

Comment: (This will only work with ATT phones btw)

Comment: ok so i changed the phone number to an email and that worked on the client server. however when i changed it back to the phone number it does not work. secondly what do you suggest for phone numbers that are not ATT and are overseas?

Comment: To send to any network anywhere you need an SMS gateway API E.g. twillo.com and many others (or you can send by interfacing with a GSM modem & SIM card)

Comment: If the email works but there is no message delivered then ATT are not sending it for some reason.  Perhaps there is send throttling, perhaps they dont like the originating emails network

Comment: are you saying throttling on the server side, or throttling on ATT side?

Comment: ATT, email-to-sms is clunky and open to abuse